# Angular FormGroup doesn't contain model property

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an API which for example returns the following model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    int Id { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

I have an Angular Reactive form with the following FormGroup:

```
myForm = new FormGroup({
  id: new FormControl(),
  userName: new FormControl(),
  firstName: new FormControl(),
  surname: new FormControl()
});
```

When I load the data into my form I receive the following error: 
Cannot find form control with name: displayName.

I know the control isn't in my form group but I don't want it there as I would never change that value on the form. Is there a way round this or do I need to add it to the form group.

The form control isn't part of the HTML.It is not referenced anywhere on the Angular side and that is what I want.

```
<input type="text" [formControl]="myForm.get('userName')"/>
<input type="text" [formControl]="myForm.get('firstName')"/>
<input type="text" [formControl]="myForm.get('surname')"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to add anything, but you need to show your template.

Comment: If you don't want to access it in your code anyways, just don't give it a formControlName.

Comment: The form control isn't part of the html and i don't want it to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs when the formControlName directive from the html template tries to look for the given name in the form. The solution would be to remove the formControlName="displayName" from the html.

Here is the function mentioned in the comment

```
   createFormGroup(data?:any):FormGroup{
     return new FormGroup({
       id: new FormControl(data ? data.id : null),
       userName: new FormControl(data ? data.userName : ''),
       firstName: new FormControl(data ? data.firstName : ''),
       surname: new FormControl(data ? data.surname : '')
     })
    }
```

Use it when you get the response

```
myForm = this.createFormGroup(response)
```

Comment: I don't have any HTML that references that formcontrol and I don't want it in the HTML

Comment: Could you give a snip where you assing the data from model to the form?

Comment: I just use the http client response: this.myForm.setValue(response)

Comment: SetValue sets the value of the FormGroup. It accepts an object that matches the structure of the group, with control names as keys. PatchValue tries to match as best as it can. So you should try it with patchValue. If it doesnt work you will need to add it to you form or make a function that accepts the model and returns the formGroup without the displayName.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you

Comment: No problem! Happy coding :)